# Are there Examples of a function with elementary antiderivative that we know its antiderivative is too big too be written down?

Tags: integration, analysis, soft-question, indefinite-integrals, examples-counterexamples

EDIT: I asked this question on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462641/how-much-complicated-can-an-elementary-antiderivative-get).

---

I recently learned that there are many very large numbers that have been defined, such as $TREE(3)$ and many others that we cannot write down.

What made me interested is the idea that there is a function that take some finite and small number to an absolute beast of a number.

So I wonder if there is some function with an elementary antiderivative that we know its antiderivative is too large to be written down, but we can write down the function itself.

> What I mean by writing down the antiderivative:  Is to write it without any shorthand notation like $\sum_n f(x_n)c_n$ Like how we can't layout the digits of $TREE(3)$ if we wanted to But the antiderivative is finite.

> What I mean to be too large is the humanity can't write it down without any shorthand notation because the antiderivative has a lot of terms (say for example $10^{10000}$ term) and composition of functions.

> What I mean by    writing down the function is: It is possible to write down its distributive form without any shorthand notation like $(1+x)^4$ i will count this as shorthand and its distributive form is $1+4x+6x^2+4x^3+x^4$  so functions like $x^{TREE(3)},\  {TREE(3)}  $ doesn't count.

Comment: $\int \mathrm{TREE}(3) dx$?

Comment: @Randall Isn't that just $x \operatorname{TREE}(3)$?

Comment: Right, but $\mathrm{TREE}(3)$ can't be written down, so....

Comment: Or you can argue that the integrand shouldn't be allowed to be the unwritable $\mathrm{TREE}(3)$ either, but then how about $\int x^{\mathrm{TREE}(3)-1} \ dx$.  Maybe $\mathrm{TREE}(3)-1$ *can* be written down, but then its integral cannot.  Where do you draw the line between writable and not?

Comment: This amusing TREE(3) discussion makes me realize that this question should really be about the complexity of the antidifferentiation operator.

Comment: @Randall I edited the question , I hope it is clear now , since english is not my langue I have a hard time wrtinig the question if you can correct my choice of words like "distributive " that would be great

Comment: A good starting point would be [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra))
Based on the form that functions with elementary antiderivatives should have, it doesn't look like their antiderivatives can get that much more complicated that the original function. Though it can also depend on what is considered complicated, because some antiderivatives may require computing roots of high-degree polynomials.

Comment: Doest it count https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4842694/closed-form-of-integral-int-0-infty-frace-x1x-cdotsdx-with-cont ?

Comment: @DesmosTutu the dominator is infinite so no

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462641/how-much-complicated-can-an-elementary-antiderivative-get

Comment: @GerryMyerson I forgot to update this question